# a thick fci bar style

Tags: emacs

I'd like to know how I can set the fci bar more thicker than the default like as [this](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYzriD6KTLAhUhx6YKHY8OAdgQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjrupac.wordpress.com%2F2010%2F11%2F02%2Ffun-with-vim%2F&psig=AFQjCNF3cc7XPsUZW6SwFQXo9ANvtXPWHQ&ust=1457104642945805). I mean like vim's ruler.

Answer (score 2):

Lines 62 to 63 of the comments at the top of the library -- https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator/blob/master/fill-column-indicator.el -- state as follows:  "*The rule's width in pixels is determined by the variable 'fci-rule-width'; the default value is 1.*"  Therefore, you can use something like `(setq fci-rule-width 5)` for 5 pixels (for example) inside your `.emacs` file -- save and restart Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Just run M-x customize-group  fill-column-indicator and you will find there are settings to change both the thickness and the colour of the fill column line.

Note that there are different variables to control graphic (which uses pixels) and terminal (which uses characters).

If you prefer to use direct settings in your .emacs or init.el file, you can copy the variable name from the customize section once you have saved your changes and put them inside a (setq ...) and then remove the corresponding lines from your customize section.

Using customize is a very handy way to explore user customizations for any package, even if you prefer to manage such things yourself.